# Gtk2Hs : Existing function not found

Tags: haskell, ghc, gtk2hs

I have a problem with Gtk2Hs, I want to set a `cellRenderer` activatable.
For that, I need to set it's property   `cellMode` to `CellRendererModeActivatable` by using :

```
set render [ cellMode:= CellRendererModeActivatable ]
```

But I have the following error when compiling

```
Not in scope: data constructor `CellRendererModeActivatable'
```

I'm using Gtk2Hs 0.12.3 on my Debian Wheezy with GHC 7.4.1.

I looked in Hackage if the constructor exist (in the correct version of the documentation) and ... **it does**.

I tried to explicity load the module

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.ModelView.CellRenderer
```

but the compilation error remain the same.

Do you have an idea where the error come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks as a bug in that old Haskell library: from its source code

```
module Graphics.UI.Gtk.ModelView.CellRenderer (
  -- snip
  CellRendererMode,
```

The above is *not* exporting the constructors. Newer versions do:

```
module Graphics.UI.Gtk.ModelView.CellRenderer (
  -- snip
  CellRendererMode(..),
```

You may try to update the Haskell library to a newer version. That should fix it.

---

**Alternative**. The type has an `Enum` instance even in the old version, so as a quick & dirty workaround you can use `toEnum 1 :: CellRendererMode` 
instead of the constructor.

```
data CellRendererMode = CellRendererModeInert         -- 0
                      | CellRendererModeActivatable   -- 1
                      | CellRendererModeEditable      -- 2
                      deriving (Enum,Eq)
```